# Get number of rows from a select count MySQL statement

Tags: php, count

```
$How_Many_Manufacturers = "SELECT COUNT(manufacturer), manufacturer
                                   FROM products
                                   WHERE name LIKE '%$new_title%'
                                   GROUP BY manufacturer";


        $result2 = mysql_query($How_Many_Manufacturers, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);

if ($num_rows == 0)
{
    echo "<div id=\"noMatches\">No Matches</div>";
                                                   }

else {

                                                   }
```

The if statement will not work. 
How can I correct this script?

Comment: In what way does it not work. What does it do incorrectly?

Comment: @JohnFx It does not allow me to echo No Matches if there is no rows; all it does it show a mysql error statement

Comment: @sdleihssirhc I unintentionally did not accept answers when I first made this account. However, I have learned that it is important to accept answers which I have been doing.

Comment: add the missing `;` after `echo` statement and you cannot have empty  `{ }`

Comment: Exactly _what_ MySQL statement do you get?

Comment: @lmre L Thanks for your suggestion. However that is not the issue. It was simply a mistake exclusively on SO, not in my script

Comment: add the ; will not change the error

Comment: You query is correct as well as the code, so my guess is that you variable $new_title is not sanitize!

Comment: add the error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Arjan You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-25,25' at line 4 -RPM

make sure you escape $new_title in the query.

```
$How_Many_Manufacturers = "SELECT COUNT(manufacturer), manufacturer
                               FROM products
                               WHERE name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($new_title)."%'
                               GROUP BY manufacturer";
```

Comment: Again, I need the actual integer of all products in the database that correspond with the manufacturer. Thus, why I am using COUNT

Comment: Its about the situation in which there is no rows

Answer (score 1):

SELECT COUNT will always return a row (even if the count is zero).  Simply remove the COUNT, or fetch the row to see the count.

Comment: @tandu I need the count for reasons related to the appliation. For example, I need to show the count of products related to the brand

Comment: That's not correct! Especially in this case, he's using GROUP BY which may return multiple rows.

Comment: What's not correct?  Even if you GROUP BY it will still return at least one row.

Comment: The select also returns the manufacturer, not only the count, so it may return an empty resultset when there are no matches.

Comment: @Arjan You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-25,25' at line 4